# Show One Category on Post

Tags: posts, categories, customization

How do i go about making the code only show one category?

```
    <?php
  $categories = get_the_category();
  foreach($categories as $key => $category) {
    $url = get_term_link((int)$category->term_id,'category');
    $categories[$key] =
      "<dt><h1>{$category->name}</h1> </dt>" .
      "<dd>{$category->category_description}</dd>";
  }
  echo "<dl>\n" . implode("\n",$categories) . "\n</dl>";
?>
```

The Reason why am asking is that I have two category(s) on some of the posts but i only want to show one of them. Is there way to add it to the code above so it only shows one thanks.

Comment: As long as you are looping trough all the categories you are getting them all, so don't do that or skip after the first run.

Comment: Well it will only show the number of category that the post has it wont show all. But i only wanted it to only show one specific one.

Comment: are you sure it won't show all humanly possible and thinkable categories? of course I'm kidding here.. ;)

Comment: Sure, my pleasure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for your question.

Try using the following code.

```
<?php
  $categories = get_the_category();
  if($categories[0]) {
    $url = get_term_link((int)$categories[0]->term_id,'category');
    $temp = "<dt><h1>{$categories[0]->name}</h1> </dt><dd>{$categories[0]->category_description}</dd>";
      echo "<dl>\n" . $temp . "\n</dl>";
  }
?>
```

Best Regards,

Vinod Dalvi

Comment: Thanks. This is what i was looking for cheers. Thank you.

Comment: @H3r0k0 You are most welcome and feel free to ask question if you face any.

Don't forget to accept answer if it works for you :)