# How to show main category related to that post

Tags: posts, categories

On my main page I have a few post from two categories, but I only want it to display only one

Here is my code

```
<?php
/* translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma */
    $categories_list = get_the_category_list( __( ', ', 'themename' ) );
        if ( $categories_list && themename_categorized_blog() ) :
?>
<?php printf( __( '%1$s', 'themename' ), $categories_list ); ?>
```

Is it possible to do it by adding this `[0]` in the code somewhere, if so, where?

Comment: Could you explain what it is you're trying to do exactly?

Comment: Yes on my main page i have a few post that show two category(s) but i only want it to show one only

Comment: I have updated your question from your comment, but still it don't make much sense. Check my answer, if it is not what you want, please be more clearer so that I can adjust my answer accordingly

Comment: @PieterGoosen Check out the earlier [question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/147663/22534) H3r0k0 asked.

Answer (score 0):

There are better suited functions to do what you want available.

In reference to your other, similar question, use [`get_the_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) like you did there. Or you can use [`get_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) or [`wp_list_categories()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_categories). What to chose depends on your needs, for example in regards to formatting.

Btw, the question, what the main category is isn't as easy answerable, if we're talking about categories on the same level.